# Modify admin panel tab position

Tags: wp-admin

I was just wondering if it's possible at all to move the position of a tab inside the admin panel.

Here's what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDz8X.png

As you can see I have plenty of custom post types, and each one except for the Slider type has position = 5 ( above media ). Unfortunately some of them are sliding below, and I am looking for a way to have media after all of them again. Not a big deal, just wondering if it's possible. Looked around but couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone might stumble upon this and have the same problem, it can be done by manipulating the admin menu itself, and there's a great tutorial for this http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/customizing-your-wordpress-admin/